# Type ... ambiguous without more context

Tags: ios, migration, swift3

On the process of migrating an iOS app to Swift 3.0. Here is one issue I am facing.

First the relevant code:

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.current,
calendCompo = calendar.components([.Year, .Month, .Day, .Hour, .Minute, .Second], fromDate: NSDate())
```

Second the problem:

I am getting this error message, for the second line:

```
Type of expression is ambiguous without more context
```

I also tried this code:

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.current,
calendCompo = calendar.components([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], fromDate: NSDate())
```

But it did not make any difference.

How do I need to modify the code to make it work?
Thanks for any relevant tip.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to achieve that in **Swift 3.0** is:

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.current,
calendCompo = calendar.dateComponents([.Year, .Month, .Day, .Hour, .Minute, .Second], from: NSDate())
```