# How to calculate days between 2 dates

Tags: swift

I have created some code which retrieves and formats the current date into the correct format and I have a second date which is a string. How can I calculate the days difference. I have read alot of posts howerver am very confused on how to implement it.

Current Code:

```
    let date = Date()
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"

    let currentDateFormatted = formatter.string(from: date)
    let endDate = "16.05.2018"
```

I have tried the following code however I am getting an error "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context".

```
    let date = Date()
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"

    let currentDateFormatted = formatter.string(from: date)
    let endDate = "16.05.2018"
    let endDateFormatted= formatter.date(from: endDate)

    let calendar = Calendar.current 
    let components = calendar.dateComponents([.day], from: currentDateFormatted, to: endDateFormatted)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41158611/type-ambiguous-without-more-context)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to convert the `endDate` string into a `Date` using the date formatter. Then pass `date` and the new `Date` to the `dateComponents` call. Then access the `day` property of the resulting `components`.

And use Calendar, not NSCalendar.

```
let startDate = Date()
let endDateString = "16.05.2018"

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"

if let endDate = formatter.date(from: endDateString) {
    let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: startDate, to: endDate)
    print("Number of days: \(components.day!)")
} else {
    print("\(endDateString) can't be converted to a Date")
}
```

Comment: I have tried to do that howerver I still get the same error. I have updated my piece of code.

Comment: You need to pass `date`, not `currentDateFormatted`.

Comment: It is now working however it is printing out "DAYS LEFT : day: 0 isLeapMonth: false " how can I make it so that it only prints just the number after the "Days Left" text

Comment: Print components.day

Comment: thanks for the help, I really appreciate the time you have taken to help with my problem. The code runs fine now.